# TCP server haskell string comparison

Tags: haskell

I have a small server written in Haskell, when I send something to it, it should evaluate if the sent content matches a password "password" in the auth function but it is never True.
I can see that the sent message gets through because it is printed at 'putStrLn msg'.
I tried several things, different functions, use of 'case of' in haskell, ... . I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, its just String comparison no?

Thanks in advance!

```
import Network
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    sock <- listenOn $ PortNumber 4242
    loop sock

loop :: Socket -> IO ()
loop sock = do
    (h,_,_) <- accept sock
    forkIO $ auth h
    loop sock

auth :: Handle -> IO ()
auth h = do
     msg <- hGetLine h
     putStrLn msg
     when (msg == "password") $ do
        server h

server :: Handle -> IO ()
server h = do
     hPutStr h "connected"
     putStrLn "connected"
     msg <- hGetLine h
     putStrLn msg
     hClose h
```

Comment: Maybe you need to strip whitespace? => Try printing the length of the string as well.
Also, try to print something in your "do" block to see whether the problem is in the string comparison or in the `server` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a number of issues here.

- You should flush `Handle` after `hPutStr h "connected"`. IIRC the `Handle` is buffered. So probably everything is ok, but you don't see the `connected` message on client side because of buffering. (ADDED: use `hFlush h`)
- Some clients (e.g. `telnet`) uses `\r\n` as end-of-line mark, but `hGetLine` expects `\n`. So you may receive `password\r` instead of `password`. Try `print msg` instead of `putStrLn msg` to see what exactly you received.

Comment: String matching on "password\r" works, indeed due to the fact that I was using telnet. Thanks!