# Socket Programming in Haskell: putStrLn / hPutStrLn not behaving as expected

Tags: sockets, haskell, io

I am currently attempting to write a toy server in Haskell, with the example at https://wiki.haskell.org/Implement_a_chat_server as a baseline for socket programming.

I'm running into an issue in which `putStrLn` and `hPutStrLn` are not behaving as I would have expected. The code at the bottom of this post is a complete example demonstrating my problem, and compiles and runs without issue as follows:

`$ ghc -main-is TestServer.main TestServer.hs`

`$ ./TestServer`

The server accepts telnet connections on port 4242 as follows:

`$ telnet localhost 4242`

It then prompts the user for their name. When entered, the user should receive the message:

**Welcome, [username]!**

But instead receives the message

**!elcome, [username]**

Note that the exclamation point seems to be moved from the end of the string and replaces the 'W'. It doesn't make a difference how long the username is, the result is the same.

Additionally, the terminal on which the server is running should then display the name of the the user as follows:

**[username] has joined the server.**

But instead displays:

**has joined the server.**

The username appears to be the empty string. However, if we simply substitute the line

`putStrLn (userName newUser)`

for the line

`putStrLn ((userName newUser) ++ " has joined the server.")`

the user's name is displayed correctly. I'm at a bit of a loss as to why I'm having these issues (the example linked to above compiles fine, and there are no such problems with putStrLn/hPutStrLn. I'm convinced it's something painfully subtle.

Here's the aforementioned code:

```
-- TestServer.hs
module TestServer where

import Control.Concurrent
import Network.Socket
import System.IO

type User = (Handle, String)

userName :: User -> String
userName (_, name) = name

main :: IO ()
main = do
    sock <- socket AF_INET Stream 0
    setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
    bind sock (SockAddrInet 4242 iNADDR_ANY)
    listen sock 2
    socketLoop sock []

socketLoop sock users = do
    (uSock, _)      <- accept sock
    uHandle         <- socketToHandle uSock ReadWriteMode
    hSetBuffering uHandle NoBuffering
    newUser         <- initUser uHandle

    putStrLn ((userName newUser) ++ " has joined the server.")

    socketLoop sock (newUser:users)

initUser :: Handle -> IO User
initUser handle = do
    hPutStr handle "Please enter your name: "
    name <- hGetLine handle
    let user = (handle, name) in do
        hPutStrLn handle ("Welcome, " ++ name ++ "!")
        return user
```

Comment: I'm almost sure you have a mess with newline characters. When you press `CR` in telnet prompt, it sends something like `\r\n`, but `hGetLine` expects only `\n`. So '\r' becomes part of the username, so "!" is printed on the beginning of the line.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219130/tcp-server-haskell-string-comparison/25219265#25219265

Comment: Thanks, that was the right approach. Sanitizing the input by stripping '\r' characters out does the trick.

Comment: Now, the meta question is: should I mark this as a dup? Would it be useful to post my solution as an answer to my own question? Or @Yuras, would you like to answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am marking the question as a duplicate, but I wanted to post my solution that came out of that question, in the event that it may prove useful, as the original question doesn't contain an explicit solution.

I wrapped calls to `hGetLine handle` as follows:

```
sanitizeInput :: Handle -> IO String
sanitizeInput handle = do
    input <- hGetLine handle
    return (sanitize input)

badChars :: [Char]
badChars = ['\r']

sanitize :: String -> String
sanitize = filter (\x -> not (elem x badChars))
```

Comment: fyi - Data.List defines `notElem`